# Footer hiding content

Tags: html, css, footer

I have the following footer that seems to be working fine but there is the problem that when I scroll down the page the footer covers the content. Does somebody have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div class="footer" id="footer">My footer</div>
```

CSS:

```
#footer {

    border: 1px groove #aaaaaa;
    background: #333333;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height:40px;

}
```

Comment: `position: fixed;` is probably the culprit here. Why are you using `position:fixed;`?

Answer (score 0):

try body `padding-bottom:40px;`

```
body{
  padding-bottom:40px;
}
```